# Illegal start of expression with "while" loop

Tags: loops, while-loop, nested

I'm a total newbie who is taking his first coding class.  I've handled everything right up until loops, which are chewing me up and spitting me out.  Right off the bat, I've run into an **Illegal start of expression** error.

```
//This program will find averages for the sets of numbers input

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class Java_Chapter_5

{
  public static void main (String args[])
  {
    //declarations
    String userIn;
    int numEntered;  
    int average;
    int totCount;
    string programStart;
    string programEnd;
    //end declarations

    System.out.println("Welcome, this program will find the average of numbers that are input");

    programStart=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter Y to start the program or N to end");

    while (programStart<>Y)
    { 
      numEntered=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter first number in the range to average or enter 0 to average numbers entered")
```

I apologize for being a total noob, but I'm so beyond lost on this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is your actual code or pseudo code, but the first thing to remember is that Strings in Java start with a capital 'S', so your declarations should read :

```
 String programStart;
 String programEnd;
```

Secondly, the expression inside of the `while` loop is not valid Java syntax for a boolean expression, ie, this symbol, `<>`, is going cause your program to fail at compile time. When you're dealing with `while` loops, the code inside of the parenthesis must be a valid expression that evaluates to either `true` or `false`. This will let the program know whether to continue the loop once the program reaches the bottom of the `while` loop code. For example `while(true)` will execute the while loop code forever, `while(false)` will never execute, and `while(x > 5)` will continue to loop so long as the variable `x` is greater than 5, ie, so long as the expression `x > 5` evaluates to `true`. In your case, you are apparently checking to make sure that the variable `programStart` equals `"Y"` in order to continue looping. With Strings in java, you can check equality like this: `programStart.equals("Y")`. So, your `while` loop condition should be

```
while (programStart.equals("Y")) { 
    //blah blah blah 
}
```